# SQL join returns so many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have two tables: Alerts(22078 rows) and Demographics(1857). The Alerts contain 2 columns: AlertID(Unique) and EndUserID. Each EndUserID can have multiple AlertID. The Demographics table contain 2 columns: EndUserID (Unique) and PIN(Unique and Null).

| AlertID | EndUserID |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 119 |
| 134 | 119 |
| 293 | 139 |
| 89 | 200 |
| 375 | 119 |
| 500 | 257 |

| EndUserID | PIN |
| --- | --- |
| 119 | 24001 |
| 500 | 23045 |
| 200 | 25901 |
| 1000 | Null |
| 439 | 20018 |
| 78 | 25457 |

I want to get the PIN for each AlertID in Alerts table from the Demographics. It should be a simple join query in workbench like:

```
Select a.AlertId, a.EndUserID, b.PIN 
from alerts a join Demographics b  
on a.EndUserID = a.EndUserID;
```

My output should look like:

| AlertID | EndUserID | PIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 119 | 24001 |
| 134 | 119 | 24001 |
| 293 | 139 | Null |
| 89 | 200 | 25901 |
| 375 | 119 | 24001 |
| 500 | 257 | 21600 |

However, I am getting so many number of rows like EndUserID 119 is returning more than 300 records with different PIN even though there are only 59 instances of it in Alerts and just 1 in Demographics.. It is very weird and I am not sure what mistake I am making.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: @nbk I bet that no. Even if he would change his join type to any of ones you listed the result wouldn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are joining all the rows in alerts table with all the rows in Demographics, there is a mistake in alias you are joining the columns on:

```
Select a.AlertId, a.EndUserID, b.PIN 
from alerts a join Demographics b  
on a.EndUserID = b.EndUserID; -- < here
```

Comment: That was so stupid of me. I spent last 30 min thinking what mistake I am doing.